# flutter change size of circle of slider

Tags: flutter, dart, slider, shapes

I use a slider and I want to change the size of the circle of the slider,
can anyone help me, please?

```
Slider(
                    activeColor: MyColors.darkGrey,
                    inactiveColor: MyColors.lightGreyTxt,
                    value: position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                    divisions: 1000,
                      min: 0.0,
                    max: value.total.inSeconds.toDouble() + 1,
                    onChanged: (double value) async {
                      var _newPosition = Duration(
                        seconds: value.toInt(),
                      );
                      setState(() {
                        position = _newPosition;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `Slider` inside `SliderTheme` and use `SliderThemeData` like this:

```dart
SliderTheme(
  data: SliderThemeData(
    thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 20),
  ),
  child: Slider(),
),
```

If you have range slider you can use `rangeThumbShape`:

```dart
SliderTheme(
  data: SliderThemeData(
    rangeThumbShape: RoundRangeSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 20),
  ),
  child: RangeSlider(),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

wrape your `Slider` with `SliderTheme` like:

```
SliderThemeData(
            thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 40)),
        child: yourSlider(),
      ),
```

Comment: it's not work and slider not change